# Cookie or local storage?

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, local-storage, token

Background: I have two apps frontend and backend. Backend is `django` with `django rest framework`. For auth I use token. Client gets the token when it logs in via `post`. Client sets this token to `header` and keeps token in `localStorage`. I save the token to `localStorage` to prevent second request after reopening the site. But I have written a lot of articles where were wrote that `localsStorage` is vulnerable and it is susceptible to `xss` attacks. And now I thing about `cookies`. But I don't want to rewrite my backend logic. And I'm thinking about writing the token to a cookie via js.

My question: Should I write token to the `cookies`? Or should I rewrite my backend application and use sessions? Or mb don't rewrite it?

Comment: you can also store that token in your application

Comment: There is no way to give a proper answer to a question like this, when you just vaguely mention some potential security issues you have read about somewhere.

Comment: I store a token in localStorage and in app. But when the tab will be closed, token in app will be lost. And when the user open the tab again, I'll take token from localStorage. @messerbill

Comment: I don't know which places should be described in more detail @CBroe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both cookies and local storage are similarly susceptible to being tampered with on the client-side: the client can see and modify both, and so can any (possibly malicious) extensions they have. But if the connection to your site is over HTTPS and their browser/OS/hardware doesn't have something malicious snooping on things, then there shouldn't be an issue with either cookies or local storage.

The main difference between them is that cookies get sent to the server with every network request, whereas local storage stays on the user's hard drive and doesn't get sent to the server.

Cookies are arguably a *little bit more* vulnerable than local storage because if a cookie gets sent over an unencrypted connection, it can be intercepted - but local storage stays on the client's machine, so there's less chance of it being intercepted by something malicious. But if the connection is encrypted, which it *should* be, using cookies will be fine.

If your script requires the token to be sent with requests to the server, you should probably use cookies so you can examine them on your back-end. (If you use local storage instead, you'll have to manually send the token with every request, which is still possible, but a bit inelegant given that cookies can do the same thing without requiring manual intervention on your part.)

If your script *doesn't* require the token to be sent with every request, then feel free to use local storage instead if you want. If the server *never* needs to see the token after it's been generated, then don't use cookies, since it'll be unnecessary overhead for no reason.

The same general logic above applies to *any* data on the client-side. If the server often or sometimes needs to see it, cookies are a good choice, if the data isn't too large. If the server never needs to see it, cookies are the wrong choice.

Comment: Thanks for this simple explanation. Very useful.